# About tags [stress], [ударение], [accent], [акцент]

Tags: discussion, bug, tags, tagging, tag-synonyms

We have tags: [stress](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stress), [ударение](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5),  [accents](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accents), [акцент](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82).

First two of them are not synonyms yet while they obviously should be, so I am requesting our moderators to merge them.

It’s not so easy with the other two. ‘accents’ is a synonym to ‘ударение’ now, and that seems quite confusing to me, because ‘ударение’ is not the only and, as far as I understand, even not the main sense for the English word ’accent’. Would not it be a synonym for ’акцент’ in sense of a pronunciation, typical to an area / social group? And should not it be ‘accent’ (in singular) rather that ‘accents’?

Comment: Looks like nobody reads the Meta and Chat posts these days...